# How to send data to server and fetched response using react native application?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to learn react native application by making  a simple login page using api call. Where I will send user name and password to api and it will give me response. But I can't do it. Well I am sharing my code here.....

```
var myRequest = new Request('<my API >', {method: 'POST', body: '{"username":this.state.uName , "password":this.state.pwd}'});
    fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
        alert('Res'+response);
    }).then(function(response) {
        alert('Blank'+response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        alert('Error'+error);
    });
```

I think the way of  passing my user name and password to server is wrong. Please give me some idea then I can understand what is wrong here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var data = {
   "username": this.state.username,
   "password": this.state.password
}

fetch("https://....", {
   method: "POST",
   headers: headers,
   body:  JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(function(response){ 
 return response.json();   
})
.then(function(data){ 
console.log(data)
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

You need to Stringify the json data to send request as Post method with Json parameters as you are trying to do...
Here is the example code for how to encode data before requesting for response

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {  
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the sample code for login :**

```
fetch(<hostURL>, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json',},
        body: JSON.stringify({ userName: <userName> ,Password: <Password>,})
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As the commentators before me stated, you simply need to stringify your JSON Body. In general, I' suggest that you incorporate e.g. [api sauce](https://github.com/skellock/apisauce) into you stack. It is a comprehensive wrapper around the axios library, providing standardized errors and an `ok` key for quick checks.